# ROR Wicked_pdf generates boxes instead kannada fonts in webfaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, wicked-pdf, webfaction

In anapplication, We use wicked_pdf gem to generate PDF. The contents of PDF are in "Kannada" language. In the local machine, we always get the correct fonts in the pdf. However when we generate PDF from the app deployed in webfaction, we get boxes in the pdf. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The content in the pdf is rendered on the server in an embedded webkit browser.

On the client end, your machine probably has all the right fonts.

Your server probably needs the right set of system fonts installed.